# Skipping keycloak's session cookie

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm using keycloak 4.3.8.final.

I want to utilize keycloak's OIDC flow with my own IDP. I don't want to use any session related capabilities from keycloak, only the authorize adn token endpoints.

All good, when user hits keycloak's authorize endpoint, get redirected to IDP, login, then get redirected back and then get token from Keycloak.
But when another user performs the same authorize/token scenario on the same browser, right away after the first one, with passed parameter prompt=login, keycloak instead of returning another token, throws the following error:

```
You are already authenticated as different user <placeholder> in this session. Please logout first.
```

Seems that even when passed prompt=login, keycloak still checks for valid session. Does anyone had the same problem as me? Does anyone has solution for the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution? One of my colleagues is facing the same problem.

Comment: I am not your collegue but i still need solution @Antoine for this issue. I am also facing same! Please help.